# Xamarin : Should you use an MVVM library and which is the best

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

With WPF I use "MVVM Light Toolkit from galasoft" but with Xamarin does it bring more functionality or simplicity to use a MVVM framework ?

And which framework is best all by being simple ?

I saw that there was "freshmvvm" but it seems that there are quite a few basic things.

Comment: It very much depends on what do you expect from the library and based on that you may choose one, available options are FreshMVVM(a personal favourite), Prism, MVVMLight, MVVMCross and there is a comparison available for these here https://github.com/rogerwcpt/xamarin-mvvvm-frameworks. Also if you are not looking for fancy features and just using an MVVM framework for Ioc/DI just go forward with traditional MVVM that XF itself provides and maybe use Autofac for DI/Ioc:https://blog.rthand.com/post/2014/01/20/Using-Autofac-with-Xamarin.aspx. Good luck! Feel free to get back if you have questions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by coding without an MVVM Framework at first, but I think I'll try FreshMvvm later. The latter seems to be the most suitable for my use.
It is true that many things are done without needing the MVVM Framework with Xamarin.Form

a very good Xamarin.form project architecture MVVM/IOC... : https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Comment: ,It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark the helpful post or your self reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> With WPF I use "MVVM Light Toolkit from galasoft" but with Xamarin
>   does it bring more functionality or simplicity to use a MVVM framework
>   ?

This part of the question is OK and I'll answer it, the rest is not and it is strictly prohibited here to ask which library is the best because there is no such thing as the best library.

Speaking of the above there is a major difference between WPF and Xamarin. You can't do some major things in WPF without passing some variables from the backend to the model which deifies the purpose of MVVM, and that's where MVVM libraries got in place, to resolve that. As this is unnecessary in Xamarin, they bring almost no value and a nice pile of problems.